# JAX best way to iterate RNGKeys?

Tags: python, jax

In JAX I find myself needing a `PRNGKey` that changes on each iteration of a loop. I'm not sure of the best pattern. I've considered

a) `split`

```py
for i in range(N):
  rng, _ = jax.random.split(rng)

  # Alternatively.
  rng = jax.random.split(rng, 1)[0]
```

b) `fold_in`

```py
for i in range(N):
  rng = jax.random.fold_in(rng, i)
```

c) use the iterator index? seems bad since the rng doesn't depend on a prior rng.

```py
for i in range(N):
 rng = jax.random.PRNGKey(i)
```

Which of these is the best pattern and why? I am leaning towards (b) as it maintains dependency on the previous rng key (e.g. passed in as an argument) but im not sure if this is really the intended use-case for `jax.random.fold_in`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JAX docs (including the [PRNG design doc](https://jax.readthedocs.io/en/latest/jep/263-prng.html)) recommend something similar to (a):

```py
for i in range(N):
  key, subkey = jax.random.split(key)
  values = random.uniform(subkey, shape)
  # key carries over to the next iteration
```

The reason this is better than splitting and throwing away the subkey is that it ensures that the streams in each iteration are independent.

Your option (b) is also safe, and in fact is the pattern that developers had in mind when creating `fold_in` (see e.g. https://github.com/google/jax/discussions/12395).

If you have a fixed number of iterations, it may be better to do all the splits once; for example:

```py
for i, key in enumerate(random.split(key, N)):
  values = random.uniform(key, shape)
```

Or if your iterations do not have sequential dependence, it's better to use `vmap` to vectorize the operation:

```py
def f(key):
  return random.uniform(key, shape)

jax.vmap(f)(random.split(key, N))
```

Comment: Just to be sure that I 100% understand the difference between splitting + throwing away vs splitting and keeping both as you show. Are you saying that if I split and throw away a subkey like in (a), this won't ensure that each iteration is independent because `split` only ensures independence of the two sub-paths, but not independence between streams of the parent key and each subkey?

Comment: The issue with splitting and throwing away is that you're re-using the key: you generate values in one iteration, then re-use it to split in the next iteration. Any key reuse like this circumvents the statistical guarantees that the split-based PRNGs are built on.

Comment: What about option c? I suspect there's no guarantee of independence across seeds. Is this correct? Might be good to add that to the answer.